# How can I make a dockerized Flask app write output to file?

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

I'm trying to make the server which hosts a (dockerized) Flask app "log" requests that are sent to it, simply by writing them to a text file.

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like

```
version: '2'

services:
  writer:
    build: writer/
    ports: 
      - 5000:5000
    container_name: writer
```

and inside the `writer` directory I have the `writer.py` file as follows, which is supposed to get the request and write it to a local file `feedback.txt`:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')

@app.route('/feedback', methods=['POST']) 
def log_feedback():
    with open("feedback.txt","a") as fo:
        fo.write(request.data.decode("utf-8"))
        print(request.data.decode("utf-8"))
        fo.write('\n')
    return 'Got it!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug = False)
```

For reference, my `Dockerfile` in the same `writer` dir is:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "writer.py" ]
```

`requirements.txt` is simply

```
flask
```

And a sample request is

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application" -X POST -d '{"Content":"Hello world"}' http://0.0.0.0:5000/feedback
```

Unfortunately, no `feedback.txt` gets written locally (e.g. outside the container). Can you hint to me the modifications I should perform e.g. in `docker-compose.yml` (e.g. with volumes?) in order to get the `feedback.txt` written and accessible on the server?

Comment: can you try using `open("/app/feedback.txt","a")` ?

Comment: Thanks! I tried doing that but the `feedback.txt` in the `writer` dir doesn't get modified :(

Comment: If you haven't specified any volumes, then no data inside a container is mapped to a host machine. [You should specify a volume](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) in your docker-compose file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add a volume in the docker-compose.yml. The path in the container should contain the folder that contains the written file. The path to local folder should contain a folder on your system where you want to see the written file.

```
version: '2'

services:
  writer:
    build: writer/
    ports: 
      - 5000:5000
    container_name: writer
    volumes:
      - /PATH/TO/YOUR/LOCAL_FOLDER:/PATH/TO/FOLDER/IN/CONTAINER
```

Comment: OK, I got it working by setting:
`open("/app/feedback.txt","a")` in the Python code as suggested by @vitr in comments; 
`- /PATH/TO/MY/LOCAL_FOLDER:/app` in the volumes in the docker-compose config as you mentioned. Thanks everyone!